Auto-Renewal Flow - Irregular Record-Triggered Flow Output
A screen flow is used to create a new Policy.
A record-triggered flow (Auto-Renewal Opportunity) runs when the Policy record is created or updated to create a Renewal Opportunity(1). On the first policy creation, the Renewal Opportunity(1) is created correctly with the CloseDate = Policy End Date.
When the Renewal Opportunity(1) is Closed Won, a record-triggered Policy Update Flow runs, the Policy Start and End dates are updated, and the checkbox Update_from_RenewalOppty is set to false. (This prevents recursion).
The trigger conditions for the Auto-Renewal Opportunity are that the Update_from_RenewalOppty checkbox is false, and the Oppty and Oppty Product lookups on the Policy are not null. The updated policy record has all the correct Policy Start and End dates.
When this next Renewal Opportunity(2) record is created, however, the CloseDate is set to the CloseDate of Renewal Opportunity(1) and not the current Policy End Date.
Debug on all the Flows shows the correct values.  But in production, this is not the case.
To conclude;

A screen flow creates a new Policy from an Opportunity record
A record-triggered flow creates a Renewal Opportunity(1) with the Close Date set by the Policy End Date
A record-triggered flow updates the Policy from the Renewal Opportunity.  The new dates are updated correctly on the Policy
The same record-triggered flow to create a Renewal Opportunity(2) runs again. On completion, the CloseDate is the Renewal Opportunity(1) value, not the updated Policy End date.

What could be causing the insertion of the Renewal Opportunity(1) CloseDate instead of the Flow variable = Policy End Date on the second renewal Opportunity record creation?
